# Strange Things - Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys I'm trying to catch all my categories descriptions inside my Category model and show them at my shop index page. So far everything working fine. All categories came perfectly at screen but just below then rails shows all categories as an array.

This is my Category controller

`class Site::HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end`

This is my index page

`

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-3">

      <h1 class="my-4">Shop Name</h1>
        <div class="list-group">
        <%= @categories.each do |cat| %>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><%= cat.description %></a>
         <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

and below you can check the issue

[image]

I appreciate for some help.

regards

Comment: `<%= @categories.each do |cat| %>` should be `<% @categories.each do |cat| %>`, `<%` not `<%=`.

Comment: Right in the corner. Thanks a lot. I miss this simple detail. thanks

Comment: Rule of thumb: any time you see a bunch of output like that on your page, look for a stray `<%= x.each` and that should be `<% x.each`.

Comment: Good trick. Learning with master. Thanks dude

Comment: Well if *master* means *guy that has made all these mistakes over and over again already*, then yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>  #remove "="
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><%= cat.description %></a>
<% end %>
```